# Curious hang on exit using pthreads

Tags: c, pthreads

While being fairly experienced at using pthread create, join and detatch, I don't do much work that uses mutexes and conditional variables. I was looking for a way to create something like a join/barrier using these only so I could avoid the overhead of doing create/join multiple times for each thread. Here is the code I wrote, but it randomly hangs on exit, other times exiting fine. As far as I can tell, all the mutexes are unlocked and the threads joined at the end. The performance is bad, so I'm not looking to use this structure for anything serious, but I want to know why it doesn't always finish. I've been staring at it so long I'm not seeing anything any more, so any help would be appreciated. It doesn't help with exit() in place of pthread_exit(). Have I made an error in my code or is there a problem with pthreads? Thanks in advance.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <pthread.h>

// gcc mutex.c -o mutex.bin -lm -O3  -Wall -ffast-math -march=native -std=c11 -fstrict-aliasing -fasm
// using gcc (Ubuntu 9.4.0-1ubuntu1~20.04.1) 9.4.0

uint64_t  get_cycles () {
  uint32_t lo,hi;
  asm  volatile("rdtsc":"=a"(lo),"=d"(hi));
  return  (( uint64_t)hi<<32 | lo);
}

pthread_mutex_t mutex_dt = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;  // Est. 1,000,000 cycle min for body
pthread_mutex_t mutex_db = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
pthread_mutex_t mutex_ec = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
pthread_cond_t  cond_dt  = PTHREAD_COND_INITIALIZER;
pthread_cond_t  cond_db  = PTHREAD_COND_INITIALIZER;
pthread_cond_t  cond_ec  = PTHREAD_COND_INITIALIZER;

uint32_t iterations = 20;
uint32_t num_threads;

void *drinktea() {
  uint32_t i, j, k;
  pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex_dt);
  for (i=0; i<iterations; i++) {
    for (j=0; j<iterations; j++) {
      for(k=0; k<100; k++) {
        if (!get_cycles()) printf("Drinking Tea...\n");
      }      
    }    
    pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex_db);
    pthread_cond_signal(&cond_dt); 
    if (i<iterations-1) {
      pthread_cond_wait(&cond_dt, &mutex_dt);  
    }
    pthread_cond_signal(&cond_db); 
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex_db);
  }
  pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex_dt);
  return NULL;
}
void *drinkbeer() {
  uint32_t i, j, k;
  pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex_db);
  pthread_cond_signal(&cond_db); 
  pthread_cond_wait(&cond_db, &mutex_db);
  for (i=0; i<iterations; i++) {
    for (j=0; j<iterations; j++) {
      for(k=0; k<100; k++) {
        if (!get_cycles()) printf("Drinking Beer...\n");
      }
    }
    pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex_ec);
    if (i<iterations-1) {
      pthread_cond_wait(&cond_db, &mutex_db);  
    }
    pthread_cond_signal(&cond_ec); 
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex_ec);
  }
  pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex_db);
  return NULL;
}

void *eatcrisps() {
  uint32_t i, j, k;
  pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex_ec);
  pthread_cond_signal(&cond_ec); 
  pthread_cond_wait(&cond_ec, &mutex_ec);
  for (i=0; i<iterations; i++) {
    for (j=0; j<iterations; j++) {
      for(k=0; k<100; k++) {
        if (!get_cycles()) printf("Eating Crisps...\n");
      }
    }
    if (i<iterations-1) pthread_cond_wait(&cond_ec, &mutex_ec);  
  }
  pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex_ec);
  return NULL;
}

int warmup() {
  uint32_t i;
  for(i=0; i<100000000; i++) {
    if (!get_cycles()) {
      printf("Warm up message\n");
    }
  };
  return 0;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  uint64_t i, cyclesstart, cyclesend, sumcycles;
  sumcycles = 0;
  pthread_t thread_id[3];
  if (warmup() != 0) exit(1);
  // Simulate join/barrier
  pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex_dt);
  pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex_db);
  pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex_ec);
  cyclesstart = get_cycles();
  pthread_create(&thread_id[0], NULL, drinktea, NULL);  // approx. 500k cycles for both 
  pthread_create(&thread_id[2], NULL, eatcrisps, NULL);
  cyclesend = get_cycles();
  printf("Pthread Create x2 Cycles = %li \n", cyclesend - cyclesstart);  
  pthread_cond_wait(&cond_ec, &mutex_ec);
  pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex_ec); 
  pthread_cond_signal(&cond_ec); 
  pthread_create(&thread_id[1], NULL, drinkbeer, NULL);
  pthread_cond_wait(&cond_db, &mutex_db);
  pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex_db); 
  pthread_cond_signal(&cond_db); 
  for (i=0; i<iterations; i++) {
    pthread_cond_wait(&cond_dt, &mutex_dt);
    pthread_cond_signal(&cond_dt); 
    if (i>0) {
      cyclesend = get_cycles();
      sumcycles += cyclesend - cyclesstart;
      printf("%li \n", cyclesend - cyclesstart);   
    }
    cyclesstart = get_cycles();
  }
  pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex_dt);
  printf("Pthread Mean Cycles = %f \n", (float)sumcycles/(iterations-1));  
  pthread_join(thread_id[2], NULL);
  pthread_join(thread_id[1], NULL);
  pthread_join(thread_id[0], NULL);
  pthread_exit(0);
  //exit(0);
}
```

A quick description of what's happening here is that the main thread creates 3 new threads, dt, db, and ec. db blocks ec at sync points, dt blocks db at sync points, and the main thread blocks dt at sync points. Also, I know there are barriers, but they're an extension to pthreads. Is there a better/faster way to do this? Thanks.

Comment: You are joining the threads incorrectly. `pthread_join(&thread_id[2], NULL);` should be `pthread_join(thread_id[2], NULL);` etc

Comment: ... and I think you should `return NULL;` (or `pthread_exit`) as the last thing in the thread functions.

Comment: Also: Add the compiler option `-fsanitize=thread` and run the program like this: `TSAN_OPTIONS=second_deadlock_stack=1 ./mutex.bin` and you'll get `WARNING: ThreadSanitizer: lock-order-inversion (potential deadlock) (pid=1718109)` at runtime with some info that may help you to find the cause of the deadlock.

Comment: Thanks Ted. That -fsanitize=thread option is useful. I didn't know about that. So the warning about lock order inversion, does that mean I can only use locks as if they're on a stack where I have to unlock them only in the inverse order in which they were locked?

Comment: No, the locks don't have to be on a stack. You can have them on the heap if you want. Always lock them in the same order from all threads.

Comment: @TedLyngmo I didn't mean where in memory. Do you know if they operate independently of other locks? 'Always lock them in the same order from all threads' suggests the answer is no. Can you point me to any documentation on this issue? Thanks.

Comment: The mutexes are independent from eachother. When you lock or unlock one, nothing happens to other mutexes (or locks).

Comment: ... but if different threads lock the same pair of mutexes in different orders then that creates a risk of deadlock.  Each thread can lock one of the two mutexes, making it impossible for either thread to proceed.  That can't happen if the application enforces a consistent relative acquisition order for each pair of mutexes or similar mutual-exclusion constructs (e.g. semaphores).